# What's the difference between putting variables as rule parameters vs in the rule body?

Tags: certora

In Certora, I can define variables as such:

```js
rule parameters_in(method f){
    // ...
}

rule parameters_out(){
    method f;
    // ...
}
```

Is there a difference?

Answer (score 0):

It has no difference where you declare it.

The only thing to remember is if you want to add a filter for `method f` then you need to declare it in rule parameters.

like so:

```js
rule r(method f, method g) filtered {
    f -> f.isView,
    g -> g.selector != exampleMethod(uint,uint).selector
      && g.selector != otherExample(address).selector
} {
    // rule body
    ...
}
```